# Behavior of switch statement with the default block at the top

Tags: java, switch-statement

I found one interesting way to use a `switch` statement in Java, and I can't catch all logic.

Can someone help to understand all details in depth?

Here is code:

```
private static int counter = 0;

public static Shape randomFactory() {

    int xVal = rand.nextInt(100);
    int yVal = rand.nextInt(100);
    int dim = rand.nextInt(100);

    switch (counter++ % 3) {
    default:
    case 0:
        return new Circle(xVal, yVal, dim);
    case 1:
        return new Square(xVal, yVal, dim);
    case 2:
        return new Line(xVal, yVal, dim);
    }
}
```

In general I understand this logic,

What exactly `default` mean here:

```
switch (counter++ % 3) {
        default:
```

And how does `switch (counter++ % 3)` find equals case? And here isn't any `brake` presented.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you are using `default` block at the very beginning of case statement, which is a bit strange since `default` means that this part of code will execute if none of the case conditions have matched. You should also check about [fall through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement). You avoided it with returns, but it is usually done with `break`.

`switch (counter++ % 3)` calculates first `counter++ % 3` and then matches it with appropriate `case`.

Answer (score 5):

`default` marks the block that would get executed if the `switch` expression does not match any `case` labels. In your example, `default` contains no `break`, so it would fall through and execute the same code as for `case 0`.

Note that, since you have a `case` label for every possible value of the `switch` expression, the `default` is effectively a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

`default` will execute when there is no matching in `case`.In this case `default` is useless since it will never execute. Consider the following case.

```
 switch(input){
    case 1:
     // do something
    break;
    case 2:
     // do something
    break;
    default:
    // if input is not 1 or 2 this will execute. 
    break;  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `default` clause is useless here: due to your `%3` it should never happen.

Would you modify the `%3` to `%4` it would catch some data, but as there is neither a `break` nor a `return` statement it would execute just like `case 0`.

Comment: In this case it is useless I agree. There is sometimes a good reason for doing this though - you should put in a default: case and throw an exception to detect future changes made outside the function. For example if you are switching on an enum and someone later adds a new enum value.

Answer (score 1):

```
default:
```

It simply means of none of the conditions in switch statement are matched code corresponding to default will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Default is one of the switch labels which contains statements to execute if none of the other labels match. From [JLS §14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

- At most one default label may be associated with the same switch statement.
- **If no case matches but there is a default label, then all statements after the matching default label in the switch block, if any, are executed in sequence.**  If all these statements complete normally, or if there are no statements after the default label, then the entire switch statement completes normally.
- If no case matches and there is no default label, then no further action is taken and the switch statement completes normally.

So in this case `default` label will do nothing as there always will be a match.

Answer (score 0):

There is no break inside default so it do nothing, it is just example of fallthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about switch statements from here -
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

default means if any case doesn't match with switch condition then default is called.

counter++ % 3 ..your counter was 0 so it will match with case 0.